# Redirecting audio output to line in

Tags: c#, windows, audio

i want to stream what i hear in my speakers to my mic. So i can play music through vent. I have tried all other methods but im using windows 7 and non of the programs work :(

I was wondering if its not to hard to just make a program in C# that takes the Audio out stream going to my speakers and redirects it into the line in plug?

Comment: Since google didn't help you very much on finding a program which does that I don't think it's going to be easy...

Comment: Try asking this on Super User.  http://superuser.com/  I vote for the cable.

Comment: This is a programming question.  Why would superuser be the right place for it?

Comment: @Steve because if there's already a way to do it, either with existing software or by a setting in vista, that would probably be a better way to do it for this scenario. Although it has been asked as a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

That would actually be a pretty intense hack to do that via software, I think. That would create an ugly feedback loop.

Of course, you could always just take a 1/8" - 1/8" stereo cable and plug one end into your audio out and the other into your audio in.

Comment: And then his computer went kabooom!

Answer (score 1):

It's not C#, but you won't find a lot of audio support in C#.  If you can use C++ or want to PInvoke, check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx) that explains how to do exactly what you are asking:  capturing what is being played to an endpoint (what Windows calls a jack or a speaker).